# How to use read_excel inside a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

when I use read_excel outside a loop it creates a normal dataframe:

```
pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

but I need to parse files in order to create dataframes, like:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/dir')
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel('/path/to/dir/%s'%(file))
```

that gives me columns: `Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2`... and the rows with some NaN values and some actual rows of the file.

Comment: You don't need the chdir: just `for filename in glob.glob("/path/to/dir/*.xlsx"): df = pd.read_excel(filename)` ... but what's the issue here? `read_excel` works just the same in a loop; are you sure your files are in a format readable by Pandas?

Comment: @AKX I don't know how but its returning a different dataframe inside the loop, with the unnamed columns

Comment: Well, you might want to add a print statement so you know which file you're reading. Chances are the file you're reading is not similar to your original `file.xlsx`.

Comment: yes, one file was different! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the excel files, given that the each file contains just one sheet, in one dataframe, you need to do something like:

```py
os.chdir('/home/carol/upload')
df = pd.DataFrame({})
for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = df.append(pd.read_excel(filename))
```

If you want to get rid of `Unnamed` column that might appear in you dataframe, you can use code below:

```py
df = df.iloc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains("^Unnamed")]
```

Comment: The issue is that read_excel returns two different things, one outside and other inside a loop

Comment: @CarolVieira Thanks for the comment, Carol. It might be helpful to provide a part of these data frames (not all of them) in your question, to make it more clear for us.

Comment: and the unnamed columns have some data that I want

Comment: @CarolVieira if the Unnamed columns contain the data you want, I suggest you take a look at the excel files. I guess there should be a problem with the files themselves and not a programming-related problem.